# How to squash the commits before I merge into master?

Tags: git, merge, git-squash

I branched out from master and worked in my new branch branchA, I made a few commits in branchA and merged master now and then into branchA to keep it updated with the latest change. Now I want to squash my commits into one commit before I merge into master, what should I do? I know `git merge --squash` can squash the commits. However, I don't want to merge it now because I'm waiting for code review approval. It's not good to use rebase too because I merged master into branchA, I'm wondering if there is any good way to squash the commits. Thanks!

Comment: You said that you've already sent the commits for review so you already made them public - isn't it too late for squash? You can always create a new branch and push it for review and abandon the previous review request, or make a squash and push with `--force` if you are permitted to do so on the remote server. Depending on what `review` means in your place it may also involve commit messages clarity, commits contents etc.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes, it is public now. But I want to have only one clean commits before it get merged in master.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED** : Added comments at end about the case where `branch` has been pushed

So you have

```
X --- X --- X --- X --- X <--(master)
       \           \
        A --- B --- M1 --- C <--(branch)
```

It sounds like once you're done you'd like

```
X --- X --- X --- X --- X --- ABC <--(master)
```

but you're not ready to put `ABC` on the `master` branch.

I assume that `A`, `B`, `M1`, and `C` have never been pushed.  If this assumption is false, I wouldn't squash them by any method.

So my first thought would be, wait for the code review and then afterward do the squash merge.  If `A`...`C` are destined to be discarded, what difference does pre-squashing them make?

But if you don't like that for some reason and *really* want to pre-squash, how about aiming for this:

```
X --- X --- X --- X --- X <--(master)
                         \ 
                           ABC <--(branch)
```

There are a few ways to get to this.  Here's one:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b temp
git merge --squash branch
git branch -f branch
git checkout branch
git branch -d temp
```

But based on discussion in comments, it now sounds like the `A`, `B`, and `C` commits have been pushed.  If that's true, then *any* technique for squashing them has drawbacks.

My best advice in that case is to merge as is, write a good commit message on the merge commit, and when looking at the history use `git log --first-parent`.  In this case the individual commits on the branch won't show in the log output, and you'll see a single commit (the merge itself) representing the entire branch just as if it were a squashed commit.

But if you don't want to follow that advice, and really must squash the changes, here's the deal:  Anyone continuing work on `branch` will have a problem.  And you can say "nobody should do that", and if your team agrees that nobody will ever do that then it'll work out.  But since `branch` is present in a shared repo, nothing would stop it from happening; and then *at best* you're going to have to deal with messy conflict resolutions.

Suppose you follow the steps above; what you *really* have is

```
X --- X --- X --- X --- X <--(master)
       \           \     \ 
        \           \      ABC <--(branch)
         \           \
          A --- B --- M1 --- C <--(origin/branch)
```

If you try to push `branch` it will fail (because `origin/branch` is not reachable from `branch`).  You could force the push, and as soon as you do that anyone with a local `branch` reference that points to `C` will start having issues.  Not that they can't be corrected, but it could become a hassle, especially if anyone "fixes" it the wrong way.

You could avoid that by never force-pushing `branch`.  You'd wait for the chance to merge your version of `branch` to master, then push `master` and delete your local `branch`.

```
X --- X --- X --- X --- X --- ABC <--(master)
       \           \
        A --- B --- M1 --- C <--(origin/branch)
```

Now, even if you force deletion of the remote `origin/branch` reference, other devs might *still* have local `branch` references pointed at `C`.  And since that history was not merged into `master` (but rather `ABC` was created to update master in a single non-merge commit), they'll have trouble if ever they merge (further changes to) `branch` into `master`.

You could get clever with a follow-up merge using strategy "ours" or something to show Git that `branch` is an ancestor of `master`... but at that point, you might as well have just done a normal merge back at the very beginning, because that merge will draw `A`, `B`, and `C` into the default log history of `master` just like a normal merge would've (i.e. such that to exclude it you could use `--first-parent`).

Again, all of this *can* be managed; but it's unnecessary hassle, which is why the best practice is: once a commit has been shared, allow it to be part of the history.